# Django escaping forward slash to pass regex

Tags: python, regex, django, url, urlencode

I am building an app using Django, but I'm running into an issue with the Django urls, regex, urlencode, and my data representation needs. I am building urls like `servicename/repos/<repo name>/...` where there are parameters in the url needed by the views to find specific repositories. This same style is also used for processing repository branch which often take the form of `bug/bug_name` or `feature/feature_name`.

In order to build my urls in Django, I made use of the regex `[^/]` pretty frequently to delimit my parameters. Obviously when I started working with branches using forward slashes, this became an issue so I tried url encoding the branch names using the `urlencode:""` tag in the Django templating system. However, Django still continues to resolve my branch names using the non-encoded forward slash.

Is there some way to either change my regex or change the urlencoding such that I can pass these branch names as parameters in the url? Assume that character swaping `/` to `_` or similar is not an option as I'm working with dozens of repos with hundreds of branches using many different naming styles. Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to provide an example of a URL pattern you use (with `[^/]`)? Why not just use the [documented capturing method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#example).